# Why is SIGINT not propagated to child process when sent to its parent process?

Tags: shell, process, signals

Given a shell process (e.g. `sh`) and its child process (e.g. `cat`), how can I simulate the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> using the shell's process ID?

---

**This is what I've tried:**

Running `sh` and then `cat`:

```
[user@host ~]$ sh
sh-4.3$ cat
test
test
```

Sending `SIGINT` to `cat` from another terminal:

```
[user@host ~]$ kill -SIGINT $PID_OF_CAT
```

`cat` received the signal and terminated (as expected).

Sending the signal to the parent process does not seem to work. **Why is the signal not propagated to `cat` when sent to its parent process `sh`?**

This does not work:

```
[user@host ~]$ kill -SIGINT $PID_OF_SH
```

Comment: The shell has a way to ignore SIGINT signals not sent from the keyboard or terminal.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

### How <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works

The first thing is to understand how <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works.

When you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, your terminal emulator sends an ETX character (end-of-text / 0x03).
The TTY is configured such that when it receives this character, it sends a SIGINT to the foreground process group of the terminal. This configuration can be viewed by doing `stty -a` and looking at `intr = ^C;`.
The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09) says that when INTR is received, it should send a SIGINT to the foreground process group of that terminal.

### What is the foreground process group?

So, now the question is, how do you determine what the foreground process group is?
The foreground process group is simply the group of processes which will receive any signals generated by the keyboard (SIGTSTP, SIGINT, etc).

Simplest way to determine the process group ID is to use `ps`:

```
ps ax -O tpgid
```

The second column will be the process group ID.

### How do I send a signal to the process group?

Now that we know what the process group ID is, we need to simulate the POSIX behavior of sending a signal to the entire group.

This can be done with `kill` by putting a `-` in front of the group ID.
For example, if your process group ID is 1234, you would use:

```
kill -INT -1234
```

---

### Simulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> using the terminal number.

So the above covers how to simulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as a manual process. But what if you know the TTY number, and you want to simulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for that terminal?

This becomes very easy.

Lets assume `$tty` is the terminal you want to target (you can get this by running `tty | sed 's#^/dev/##'` in the terminal).

```
kill -INT -$(ps h -t $tty -o tpgid | uniq)
```

This will send a SIGINT to whatever the foreground process group of `$tty` is.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that signals that come directly from the terminal bypass permission checking, so Ctrl+C always succeeds in delivering signals unless you turn it off in the terminal attributes, whereas a `kill` command might fail.

Comment: +1, for `sends a SIGINT to the foreground process group of the terminal. `

Comment: Worth mentioning that the process group of the child is the same as the parent after `fork`. Minimal runnable C example at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465112/32558

Comment: Important note: `tpgid` and `pgid` are not the same thing. `pgid` is the process group id, while `tpgid` is the terminal process group id. From within a process you can change its `pgid` using os.setpgid() for example, but this does not change the `tpgid`. Source: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ps1.html

Answer (score 18):

As [vinc17 says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149743/340031), there’s no reason for this to happen. 
When you type a signal-generating key sequence
(e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>),
the signal is sent to all processes that are attached to
(associated with) the terminal. 
There is no such mechanism for signals generated by `kill`.

However, a command like

```
kill -SIGINT -12345
```

will send the signal to all processes in *process group* 12345;
see [kill(1)](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/kill.1.php)
and [kill(2)](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/kill.2.php). 
Children of a shell are typically in the shell’s process group
(at least, if they’re not asynchronous),
so sending the signal to the negative of the PID of the shell may do what you want.

---

### Oops

As [vinc17 points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149741/80216#comment243396_149745), this doesn’t work for interactive shells. 
Here’s an alternative that *might* work:

```
kill -SIGINT -$(echo $(ps -pPID_of_shell o tpgid=))
```

`ps -pPID_of_shell` gets process information on the shell. 
`o tpgid=` tells `ps` to output only the terminal process group ID, with no header. 
If this is less than 10000, `ps` will display it with leading space(s);
the `$(echo …)` is a quick trick to strip off leading (and trailing) spaces.

I did get this to work in cursory testing on a Debian machine.

Comment: This doesn't work when the process is started in an interactive shell (which is what the OP is using). I don't have a reference for this behavior, though.

Answer (score 12):

The question contains its own answer. Sending the `SIGINT` to the `cat` process with `kill` is a perfect simulation of what happens when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

To be more precise, the interrupt character (`^C` by default) sends `SIGINT` to every process in the terminal's foreground process group. If instead of `cat` you were running a more complicated command involving multiple processes, you'd have to kill the process group to achieve the same effect as `^C`.

When you run any external command without the `&` background operator, the shell creates a new process group for the command and notifies the terminal that this process group is now in the foreground. The shell is still in its own process group, which is no longer in the foreground. Then the shell waits for the command to exit.

That's where you seem to have become the victim by a common misconception: the idea that the shell is doing something to facilitate the interaction between its child process(es) and the terminal. That's just not true. Once it has done the setup work (process creation, terminal mode setting, creation of pipes and redirection of other file descriptors, and executing the target program) the shell *just waits*. What you type into `cat` isn't going through the shell, whether it's normal input or a signal-generating special character like `^C`. The `cat` process has direct access to the terminal through its own file descriptors, and the terminal has the ability to send signals directly to the `cat` process because it's the foreground process group. The shell has gotten out of the way.

After the `cat` process dies, the shell will be notified, because it's the parent of the `cat` process. Then the shell becomes active and puts itself in the foreground again.

Here is an exercise to increase your understanding.

At the shell prompt in a new terminal, run this command:

```
exec cat
```

The `exec` keyword causes the shell to execute `cat` without creating a child process. The shell is replaced by `cat`. The PID that formerly belonged to the shell is now the PID of `cat`. Verify this with `ps` in a different terminal. Type some random lines and see that `cat` repeats them back to you, proving that it's still behaving normally in spite of not having a shell process as a parent. **What will happen when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> now?**

Answer:

> SIGINT is delivered to the cat process, which dies. Because it was the only process on the terminal, the session ends, just as if you'd said "exit" at a shell prompt. In effect cat *was* your shell for a while.

Comment: *The shell has gotten out of the way.* +1

Comment: I don't understand why after `exec cat` pressing `^C` wouldn't just land `^C` into cat. Why would it terminate the `cat` which has now replaced the shell? Since the shell's been replaced, the shell is the thing that implements the logic of sending SIGINT to its children upon receiving `^C`.

Comment: The point is that the shell *doesn't* send SIGINT to its children. The SIGINT comes from the terminal driver, and is sent to all foreground processes.

Comment: @StevenLu Your comment is pretty old but I'll answer your question to help other people that find this answer in the future: when you run `exec cat` you literally replace the shell executable in memory with `cat` and keep using the same process id as far as the kernel is interested. Your terminal is now running `cat` instead of your shell and the stdin, stdout and stderr are connected to `cat`. When you now press `Ctrl+C` *your terminal* interprets that as a command to send SIGINT to foreground process group. That group includes only `cat`. And `cat` handles that signal by quitting immediately

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to propagate the `SIGINT` to the child. Moreover the [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) POSIX specification says: "The system() function shall ignore the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals, and shall block the SIGCHLD signal, while waiting for the command to terminate."

If the shell propagated the received `SIGINT`, e.g. following a real <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, this would mean that the child process would receive the `SIGINT` signal twice, which may have unwanted behavior.

Comment: The shell doesn't have to implement this with `system()`. But you're right, if it catches the signal (obviously it does) then there's no reason to propagate it downward.

Comment: @goldilocks I've completed my answer, perhaps giving a better reason. Note that the shell cannot know whether the child has already received the signal, hence the problem.

Comment: @vinc17 I think that shell could ask the child if it has already gotten the SIGINT if it really wanted: `waitpid(child_pid, wstatus, WUNTRACED | WNOHANG | WNOWAIT)` followed by `WIFCONTINUED(*wstatus)`. Haven't tested if I've misunderstood something, though.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I don't think that `waitpid` is correct, because the child may trap `SIGINT` and choose not to terminate on one `SIGINT`, but terminate on two (some tools behave like that). So, if it receives a second `SIGINT` from its parent (thinking that its child didn't receive one), this would be bad. Moreover, there could be a race condition with `waitpid`.

Comment: waitpid() will return immediately with the flags I had in the example. Return value can be used to check if child has received SIGINT. It was response to "shell cannot know whether the child has already received the signal".

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I still don't see how you can know whether the child has received a `SIGINT`. You said `WIFCONTINUED(*wstatus)`. But [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) specifies `WIFCONTINUED` as: "Evaluates to a non-zero value if status was returned for a child process that has continued from a job control stop." And there is no stopped job involved here. And `WIFCONTINUED` does not say anything about `SIGINT`.

Answer (score 1):

**`setpgid` POSIX C process group minimal example**

It might be easier to understand with a minimal runnable example of the underlying API.

This illustrates how the signal does get sent to the child, if the child didn't change its process group with `setpgid`.

main.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t is_child = 0;

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    char parent_str[] = "sigint parent\n";
    char child_str[] = "sigint child\n";
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
        if (is_child) {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, child_str, sizeof(child_str) - 1);
        } else {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, parent_str, sizeof(parent_str) - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pid_t pid, pgid;

    (void)argv;
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_handler);
    pid = fork();
    assert(pid != -1);
    if (pid == 0) {
        is_child = 1;
        if (argc > 1) {
            /* Change the pgid.
             * The new one is guaranteed to be different than the previous, which was equal to the parent's,
             * because `man setpgid` says:
             * > the child has its own unique process ID, and this PID does not match
             * > the ID of any existing process group (setpgid(2)) or session.
             */
            setpgid(0, 0);
        }
        printf("child pid, pgid = %ju, %ju\n", (uintmax_t)getpid(), (uintmax_t)getpgid(0));
        assert(kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1) == 0);
        while (1);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    /* Wait until the child sends a SIGUSR1. */
    pause();
    pgid = getpgid(0);
    printf("parent pid, pgid = %ju, %ju\n", (uintmax_t)getpid(), (uintmax_t)pgid);
    /* man kill explains that negative first argument means to send a signal to a process group. */
    kill(-pgid, SIGINT);
    while (1);
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/0dc030e6040b6a21ca854c6e8fa28b722646d15e/posix/interactive/setpgid.c).

Compile with:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o setpgid setpgid.c
```

**Run without `setpgid`**

Without any CLI arguments, `setpgid` is not done:

```
./setpgid
```

Possible outcome:

```
child pid, pgid = 28250, 28249
parent pid, pgid = 28249, 28249
sigint parent
sigint child
```

and the program hangs.

As we can see, the pgid of both processes is the same, as it gets inherited across `fork`.

Then whenever you hit:

```
Ctrl + C
```

It outputs again:

```
sigint parent
sigint child
```

This shows how:

- to send a signal to an entire process group with `kill(-pgid, SIGINT)`
- Ctrl + C on the terminal sends a kill to the entire process group by default

Quit the program by sending a different signal to both processes, e.g. SIGQUIT with `Ctrl + \`.

**Run with `setpgid`**

If you run with an argument, e.g.:

```
./setpgid 1
```

then the child changes its pgid, and now only a single sigint gets printed every time from the parent only:

```
child pid, pgid = 16470, 16470
parent pid, pgid = 16469, 16469
sigint parent
```

And now, whenever you hit:

```
Ctrl + C
```

only the parent receives the signal as well:

```
sigint parent
```

You can still kill the parent as before with a SIGQUIT:

```
Ctrl + \
```

however the child now has a different PGID, and does not receive that signal! This can seen from:

```
ps aux | grep setpgid
```

You will have to kill it explicitly with:

```
kill -9 16470
```

This makes it clear why signal groups exist: otherwise we would get a bunch of processes left over to be cleaned manually all the time.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.