# How come `while true; do echo y; done | true` dies on its own, but `while true; do echo y | cat; done | true` doesn't?

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe, signals

To be clear with the title question, I understand why the former dies. I don't understand why the latter doesn't, just for adding a `| cat` to the loop body.

Also maybe related,

```
while true; do echo y; done
```

dies immediately when I do `^C`, but killing

```
while true; do echo y | cat; done
```

often takes hitting `^C` more than once. Sometimes once works, other times 2 or 3 times works, then there are times where I need to hold `^C` for a while for it to die.

Both behaviors happen in both bash and zsh, although the `^C` one seems to be rarer with bash.

For both behaviors, this isn't limited to adding the pipe to `cat`. `| dd`, `| tee`, etc. also cause them. Even `echo y | true` causes it. It seems to be the presence of any pipe in the loop body.

Why does the presence of a pipe in a loop body change the loop's response to signals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `while true; do echo y; done | true`, since `echo` is builtin, you've a go a subshell process that write `y\n` in a loop to a pipe.

When `true` returns, the reading end of that pipe is closed, so writing to the writing end causes a `SIGPIPE` to be delivered to the writing process. Here, that's the subshell process that's running the loop.

In `while true; do echo y | cat; done | true`, it's `cat` which writes to the pipe. `cat` is generally not builtin, and even if it were, in shells other than zsh and ksh, all pipes component always run in child processes.

So, here only the process running `cat` dies and the subshell process that runs the loop carries on running more `cat` processes that die as soon as they write `y\n` on their stdout.

In ksh93/ksh2020, if you do:

```
$ builtin cat
$ type cat
cat is a shell builtin
$ set -o pipefail
$ while true; do echo y | cat; done | true; kill -l "$?"
PIPE
```

This time, `cat` is builtin and does run in the same process as the loop (as `cat` is the rightmost command in the first pipe line and ksh doesn't run that one in a subshell), so the subshell pipes to `true` does exit and `kill -l` confirms it was killed by a SIGPIPE.

Comment: Thanks! Everything makes a lot of sense now, and for the other case, after checking [how `^C` works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149756/189744), I guess `^C` stopping the loop depends on whether an external program is currently running or not. In my example with the pipe, it only works if it's delivered in between iterations. The one without the pipe doesn't have external invocations, so it always works. It also explains why more conventional loops with external programs that last longer and have in-between shell code almost always take exactly 2 `^C` in quick succession to kill the loop.